# How would I use a windowing pattern to capture session time on old log data?

Tags: apache-spark

I have web log traffic.

I'd like to reprocess old log data sequentially from a spark cluster. I want to capture user a user session, the pages visited in a single sitting. For example a person starts browsing our website and then is inactive for an hour. That would count as one session. I want to capture all the pages they visited in sequence while they were continuously browsing.

With spark streaming sources like kafka this can be done with a time window. But I want to reprocess old logs can capture session information. Can I use a timestamp column in the data itself to somehow simulate a time window processing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with window() function on normal dataframes. 
It's available on org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
example

```
df.groupBy(window($"time", "60 minutes"), $"visitorId")
  .agg(count("sessionStartTime"))
```